# On 18,04 upgrade to 20.04: "Do you want to Start" Dialog too high, buttons not visible

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, xfce, resize, dialog

Running Xubuntu Xfce 4.12
My laptop screen is 7.5 inches high inside bezel. The dialog box is too tall and doesn't show "cancel" and "ok" buttons. The window "resize" command is greyed. How do I respond? Now I'm not so sure I want to upgrade from 18.04. Can I just restart Linux? How can I cancel the upgrade?

Comment: I will give my 2c but I can't speak with authority here sorry. Laptop screen size doesn't matter; it's resolution.  I've encountered this issue & know bugs are filed, but in your position I'd just kill the GUI process, and upgrade from terminal instead using command provided in release notes. I'd not expect issues from the killed process, but if any occurred I'd just logout, maybe even reboot, ensure system is good then upgrade using text terminal.  I can't recall procedures that were QA-tested for this situation sorry (*this maybe a verified work-around & why I'm recall it, but I'm unsure*)

Comment: I thought of killing the the GUI and I looked in task manager, but I didn't know how to identify the correct task entry. How do I find the correct entry? Or do I use some other method?

Comment: I don't know which method you chose but as the [documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FocalUpgrades) says `update-manager` for GUI by default it's likely that. If it's only waiting for you to respond (*and hasn't started the upgrade as I read your question*) there is minimal risk to just logging out.  From text terminal you can use the server tool (`do-release-upgrade`)   FYI:  If you used the [Xubuntu docs](https://docs.xubuntu.org/latest/user/C/migrating-upgrading.html) I believe it'd be the same

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'll just log out and stick with 18.04 .

Comment: Please don't forget Xubuntu 18.04 is EOL (see https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/) so be aware that only parts of your system that are common with Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS get security-fixes. You can use `ubuntu-support-status` to check the security status of your installed system.  Upgrade via re-install works too (*I used it on a few boxes as it's faster; re-use existing partitions & don't format any... if internet is available it'll re-install your manually installed packages if available for new release in Ubuntu repositories; also if using encrypted home an extra package is required*)

Comment: Logout, login, problem solved.  RE: your install options; the laptop is dual-boot with Windows 10 and some  settings modified to let Linux see windows partition. I don't remember what those are. Wish I kept notes.